# VI Editor messed up.. Even the old vi is not working now

Tags: installation, updates, vim, vi

I am a newbie in Ubuntu. I am using a **Windows XP machine (32 bit) OS** and in that I installed **VMPlayer and got iso image of Ubuntu 12.04** (downloaded from online). I started the Ubuntu and everything was fine. I heard where is issue with vi editor for that we need to update / install vim. First I tried sudo apt-get update, it was throwing many connection errors. Then somewhere i read to remove the vim-tiny and do a install of vim-full again. While doing I completely messed up with the VI. Now, even the old vi is not working. How to fix it?.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling vim.

```
sudo apt-get remove vim && sudo apt-get install vim
```